# Identificador no declarado c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-c++, opengl

Estoy tratando de hacer un codigo, pero me arroja estos errores, he intentado solucionar con la documentación de microsoft, pero por la descripción del error parece estar todo en orden, lo estoy sacando de un libro de desarrollo de videojuegos en c++ y también estoy haciendo comparaciones y todo parece estar bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el código de la clase Player es:

```
#include "Player.h"

void Player::init(std::string textureName, sf::Vector2f position,
float mass) {
p_position = position;
p_mass = mass;
p_grounded = false;
// Load a Texture
p_texture.loadFromFile(textureName.c_str());
// Create Sprite and Attach a Texture
p_sprite.setTexture(p_texture);
p_sprite.setPosition(p_position);
p_sprite.setOrigin(p_texture.getSize().x / 2,
p_texture.getSize().y / 2);
}
void Player::update(float dt) {
p_force -= p_mass * m_gravity * dt;
p_position.y -= p_force * dt;
p_sprite.setPosition(p_position);

if (p_position.y >= 768 * 0.75f) {
    p_position.y = 768 * 0.75f;
    p_force = 0;
    p_grounded = true;
    jumpCount = 0;
 }
}
```

Mientras que el código del header es:

```
#include "SFML-2.5.1\include\SFML\Graphics.hpp"

class Player {
public:
Player();
~Player();
void init(std::string textureName, sf::Vector2f position, float
    mass);
void update(float dt);
void jump(float velocity);
sf::Sprite getSprite();
private:
sf::Texture p_texture;
sf::Sprite p_sprite;
sf::Vector2f p_position;
int jumpCount = 0;
float p_mass;
float p_velocity;
float p_force;
const float m_gravity = 9.80f;
bool p_grounded;
};
```

No veo que haya ninguna variable con un nombre repetido o distinto al del header :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A priori me parece un problema de que el método de compilación no reconoce el header. Todas las declaraciones que tienes en el header no son vistas por el sistema.

No se exactamente que método usas para compilar (CmakeLists.txt igual?) pero lo que deberias hacer es que el sistema lo reconociera correctamente.

Comment: Hola que tal, era un problema similar, el header necesitaba ser guardado como un archivo unix, por alguna razón tengo problemas para incluir librerías y usar paths que contengan el carácter \ pero arreglando este problema se solucionó lo demás, me diste una buena pista del problema :)

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: @Jesus pone un respuesta real con lo que pasaba entonces. No aceptes una respuesta que en realidad no soluciona el problema...